# Capturar una excepción desde un controlador PHP Zend 2

Tags: php, controller, nullpointerexception, zend

¿alguien sabe cómo capturar una excepción lanzada desde un controller usando el framework Zend 2? Por ejemplo:

```
public function func1Action ()
{
     throw new \Exception('texto de la excepción');
}
```

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

hay más info en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210609/zf2-catching-an-exception-in-the-dispatch-error-event

Cuando lanzas una excepción desde un controlador de Zend 2 la excepción se convierte a un evento.

Tienes que poner en el Module.php de tu módulo la siguiente línea en la función onBootstrap:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    ...
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    ...
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, array($this, 'dispatchError'), 100);
}
```

Y luego crear una función dispatchError() en el mismo Module.php que gestione el código de tu excepción. Ejemplo:

```
public function dispatchError ($event)
{
    if ($event->getError() == 'error-exception') {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($event->getParam('exception'));
    }
    die;
}
```

Saludos,